# In C#, how do I replace a Func with a delegate in a function parameter?

Tags: c#, delegates, parameter-passing, func

Looking at the following function that expects another Function with an output type `T` and simply calls it at returns the result:

```cs
T CallFunction<T>(Func<T> lambda)
{
  return lambda();
}
```

I would expect that I could replace `Func<T> lambda` with `delegate T lambda<T>()`. However that seems not possible, I cannot do something like:

```cs
T CallFunction<T>(delegate T lambda<T>())
{
  return lambda();
}
```

or:

```cs
delegate T MyLambda<T>();

T CallFunction<T>(MyLambda lambda)
{
  return lambda();
}
```

Is just my syntax wrong or do I not fully understand yet what [Delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.delegate?view=net-8.0) and [Func](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1?view=net-8.0) is?
Isn't `Func<T> lambda` just a delegate that returns type `T` in this case?

Comment: `delegate T lambda<T>()` makes no sense. C# doesn't support inline function pointer declarations. You need to predefine the delegate type, hence the existence of the generic `Func` types.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think I understand it more now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there, the `lambda` is a generic delegate and you have to provide the generic argument

```
delegate T MyLambda<T>();

T CallFunction<T>(MyLambda<T> lambda)
{
  return lambda();
}
```

Note

```
T CallFunction<T>(MyLambda<T> lambda)
```

instead of yours

```
T CallFunction<T>(MyLambda lambda)
```

The the first attempt

```
T CallFunction<T>(delegate T lambda<T>())
```

is illegal as it would introduce a new type in a function parameter declaration. The `delegate` keyword can be used when defining an anonymous function (to be passed as an argument) but it cannot be used to declare a parameter type. In other words, you could **call** the `CallFunction` passing an anonymous delegate

```
CallFunction<int>( delegate { return 1; } );
```

Comment: Wohoo, thats it, thanks. I guess there is no way to define it inline? Like:  `T CallFunction<T>(delegate T lambda<T>()) {...}`?

Comment: @dan-kli there is - by using the predefined `Func<T>` =))

Comment: Hehe, okay fair point :)

Comment: Why exactly can I not use the `delegate` keyword as a function parameter type? It introduces a new type? Is there a list of all allowed types, or how does it work?

Comment: _"Why exactly can I not use the delegate keyword as a function parameter type"_ - because language was designed in this way. That's it. `delegate` keyword has only 2 usages (as I wrote in comments to my answer). You can accept `Delegate` type but arguably it is not useful in your case.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 4):

`Func<T>` itself is [a delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1?view=net-8.0):

```
public delegate TResult Func<out TResult>();
```

And the second substitute attempt is missing generic parameter for the `MyLambda` delegate (the same as you do with `Func<T>` in `T CallFunction<T>(Func<T> lambda)`):

```
T CallFunction<T>(MyLambda<T> lambda)
{
   return lambda();
}
```

Comment: Yup, thats it, thank you for your help. Both answers are pretty good and show where I was wrong

Comment: @dan-kli no, at least as far as I know (as I wrote in comments to the other answer - use `Func` =) ). [`delegate` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/delegate-operator) allows only to create an anonymous method that can be converted to a delegate type. And `delegate` keyword allows you to declare custom [delegate types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/). That's it. C# mainly does not allow to create inline type definitions (the only exception out of my head - value tuples).

Comment: Ah cool, I think I am starting to understand it now. Thanks